# Why is Mathematica not simplifying further?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After I use Simplify on an expression I get$\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\dfrac{\sqrt{(-b^2+16|c|^2)(4|c|^2+b\Im(c))^2}}{4a(4|c|^2+b\Im(c)])}}$. This expression can clearly be simplified further by noticing that the square bracket term in the numerator cancels the other bracket term in the denominator so $\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\dfrac{\sqrt{(-b^2+16|c|^2)}}{4a}}$. This is clearly a much simpler form since it includes less terms, so my question is why does not mathematica do this?

Edit: here is my code

```
real[x_, y_] := -2 a x^3 - 2 a y^2 x + 2 Re[c] x + 2 Im[c] y + b/2 y;
imaginary[x_, y_] := -2 a x^2 y - 2 a y^3 + 2 Im[c] x - 2 Re[c] y - b/2 x;
sol = Solve[{real[x, y] == 0, imaginary[x, y] == 0},{x,y}];
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(x /. sol[[2, 1]])^2 + (y /. sol[[2, 2]])^2],
Assumptions -> {(a | b) ∈ Reals && c ∈ Complexes && (a | b | c) > 0}]
```

Comment: Your expectation is only true if you assume the expression to be `  Real>0 `

Comment: What do you mean by `!=0`? Is it not equal to zero? When I use the Simplify function I've included the assumption that $a,b,c>0$

Comment: != stands for not equal.

Comment: Please  give your mathematica code. What about `bJ(c)` ? Is this a function?

Comment: Okey, but I have used included the assumption in the Simplify function that $a,b,c>0$ so the expression in the bracket must thus be $>0$

Comment: @UlrichNeumann $b$ is simply a constant and it is not a J it is $\Im$ which stand for the imaginary part of $c$ since $c$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given contradictive assumptions. In Mma the condition that a variable, say, c, is positive (`c>0`) automatically means that it belongs to Reals. Thus, when you fix `c ∈ Complexes && (a | b | c) > 0` you mislead Mma.

According to your initial expressions the parameters a and b are Reals and positive, while c is Complex, am I right? If yes, try this:

```
    expr = Simplify[Sqrt[(x /. sol[[2, 1]])^2 + (y /. sol[[2, 2]])^2], 
      Assumptions -> {a, b} > 0];

MapAt[PowerExpand, expr, {2, 1}]

(*  1/2 Sqrt[-((I Sqrt[b^2 - 16 Im[c]^2 - 16 Re[c]^2])/a)]  *)
```

Have fun!

**Edit**: To address your question:

{2,1} is a TreeCoordinate of the part of the whole expression that is under the outer square root. The Tree you can visualize by the function

```
TreeForm[expr]
```

yielding the following structure

[image]

Here the arrow indicates the element {2,1} that wee need. This can be made visible, if you hover the cursor over this element. 
It is this element that the PowerExpand function is convenient to be applied to.

Comment: Yes a,b are real and positive while c is complex. True, good that you pointed that out that assuming `c>0` is misleading. What does exactly the `{2,1}` term in MapAt do?

Comment: @Turbotanten Please have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The "bracket" you want to simplify is complex!

```
bracket = r Exp[I φ];(* stands for (4 c Conjugate[c] + b Im[c])*)

expr = Sqrt[bracket^2]/bracket ;
FullSimplify[ expr, {Element[{r, φ}, Reals], r > 0 }]   
(* E^(-I φ) Sqrt[E^(2 I φ)] *)
```

Further simplification needs information about  `φ`

Comment: What do you mean by the bracket I want to simplify is complex? There is no imaginary unit in my expression.

Comment: @Turbotanten: The "bracket" is the expression `(4 c Conjugate[c] + b Im[c])` which is complex!  By the way your restrictions `c>0 and c complex` cannot be fullfilled both.